# SVG Pan Zoom Library - How to increase Zoom sensitivity?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, arrays

Refering to SVG Pan Zoom Library at https://github.com/bumbu/svg-pan-zoom, there is a section for faster or slower zooming. I have created this zoom in and out with Pan Functionality in my snippet below, but the zooming in and out is not sensitive enough, may I know how to implement the above example in github to increase the zoom sensitivity? Any help will be very much appreciated :)

Well, I have tried to implement this zoomScaleSensitivity, but it seems to have no effect on increasing zoom sensitivity which is dissapointing :)

```js
let paths = document.querySelectorAll('path');
// paths is an html collection of all paths;
// attach event listeners to each path;
for (let i=0; i<paths.length; i++) {
  paths[i].addEventListener('click', displayAlert);
} 

function displayAlert(event) {
  alert(event.target.dataset.key)
}


$(".each-row").on("click touchend",function(){
  alert("Clicked on "+ $(this).data('name'));
});

var area = document.getElementById('zoomPanCont');
var instance = "";


instance  = panzoom(area, { 
  bounds: false,
  maxZoom: 10.55,
  minZoom: 0,
   zoomScaleSensitivity:0.8,
  zoomDoubleClickSpeed: 1
});


    function resetBuilding(){
    $(this).instance = panzoom(area, { 
        bounds: true,
        maxZoom: 1.55,
        minZoom: 0,
        zoomDoubleClickSpeed: 1
        }).zoomAbs( 0, 0, 1);
    }


    $("#btnResetZoom").on("click",function(){
        resetBuilding();
    });
    $("#btnZoomIn").on("click",function(){
        instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 1.25);
    });
    $("#btnZoomOut").on("click",function(){
        instance.smoothZoom(0, 0, 0.8);
    });
```

```css
.main-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #ccc;
}


.pan-zoom-control {
    width: 30px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    font-size: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}


.pan-zoom-control button.btn-reset {
    width: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/panzoom@7.1.2/dist/panzoom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div class="main-container">
    <div id="zoomPanCont" class="zoompan-container">    
    <svg id="" data-name="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 800 600">             
        <path data-key="12345" transform="matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,600)" stroke-width="3" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="none" stroke="#000000" d="M 224.34 585.57 L 224.34 586.6 L 225.22 588.68 L 226.1 589.71 L 227.87 590.75 L 231.39 590.75 L 233.15 589.71 L 234.04 588.68 L 234.92 586.6 L 234.92 584.53 L 234.04 582.46 L 232.27 579.35 L 223.46 568.98 L 235.8 568.98 "/>
            </svg>
    </div> 

</div>
```

```
I have tried zoomScaleSensitivity, but its not working for me
instance  = panzoom(area, { 
  bounds: false,
  zoomScaleSensitivity: 10,
  maxZoom: 10.55,
  minZoom: 0,
  zoomDoubleClickSpeed: 1
});
```

Comment: As per [the posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), don't post images of text, and certainly don't post screenshots of a codepen when you can just link to that codepen, but realize that your post can, and should, contain [mcve] code if you're just working on html/css/js by using a runnable snippet. No need for links to third party websites that might not exist a few years from now.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, sorry Mike, do you understand the question above, hoping you might give a hint :)

Comment: Please [edit] your post first.

Comment: By "not sensitive enough" do you mean you want it to scale more per scroll step, or something else?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, yes exactly, more zoom in per scroll step :), sir

Comment: Looking at the docs, and a quick look at the code, `zoomScaleSensitivity` should affect zoom, so this feels like it's actually a bug that you should probably file over on https://github.com/bumbu/svg-pan-zoom/issues with your STR to show that changing that value does not change scaling behaviour.